# Fetching recent post from 3 different tables limiting the results to 5 in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 3 tables named post, exam and vacancy. I need to fetch recent posts limiting the results to total 5 count. I have a sidebar widget just like wordpress has to display most recent post, but wordpress had only one table for posts.

I'm not sure how to write the query.

Comment: It is in wordpress or Codeigniter?

Comment: write your simple query, I will convert it in codeigniter

Comment: its kind of this 
    select * from post, vacancy, exam where post_status = "Published" && exam_status = "Published" && vacancy_status = "Published"
    order by post_date, vacancy_post_date, exam_post_date DESC limit 5

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

EDIT:

```
public function recent_posts ()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('post AS a, vacancy AS b, exam AS c');
    $this->db->where('a.status = "Published"')->where('b.status = "Published"')->where('c.status = "Published"');
    $this->db->order_by('a.post_date, b.post_date, c.post_date', 'DESC');
    $this->db->limit(5);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows() != 0)
    {
        return $query->result_array();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: All the 3 Tables do not share any common column, so b,exam_id=a.exam_id is invalid as post table does not have a exam_id column

Comment: just a moment i will modify

Comment: also the post dates are UNIX timestamp, so sort should be DESC. The column names are post_date, vacancy_post_date, exam_post_date

Comment: Here's the problem with it. All the three tables are joined. I want to display a list of recent posts from each table based on descending order of sort of post date with a total of 5 results. I want to later display those results in a list, so joining the tables, isnt a gud idea.

Comment: Where do you see a join?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87583/discussion-between-cyberrspiritt-and-ilan-hasanov).

Comment: helped pretty much but isnt the answer to the question. Thanx @Ilan